# JAVA NIO Bytebuffer.allocateDirect() size limit over the int

Tags: java, nio, bytebuffer

I am trying to make off-heap memory buffer. I want very big size(like 10GB) buffer.
I heard that jvm heap sometimes freeze because full GC. So, I try to make buffer with java.nio.ByteBuffer.

But, I met great difficulties!

```
java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(int size)
```

function only support integer. but I want bigger size. what can I do? what should I do? please help me stack overflow gurus.

my development environment is macbook pro, i7 2.4ghz, 16gb ddr3, 250ssd, osx 10.9, eclipse kepler x64.

I try something for solve problem:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024*1024*2000);
ByteBuffer buffer1 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024*1024*2000);
ByteBuffer buffer2 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024*1024*2000);
ByteBuffer buffer3 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024*1024*2000);
```

but this is not works. only allocate memory 1024*1024*2000 again

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make a single buffer that big. Period. You can make several smaller ones and select amongst them as you need to in your own code. That's all you can do.

e.g.:

```
ByteBuffer[] myBuffers = new ByteBuffer[howMany];
for (int x = 0; x < howMany; x++) {
    myBuffers[x] = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(prettyBig);
}
```

and then

```
byte getByte(long index) {
    int bufx = index / howMany;
    int bx = index % howMany;
    return myBuffers[bufx].get(bx); 
}
```

Comment: so you means if i make small buffer many times, there total sizes can be over 2^31 ? when I allocate many times, I can't see memory increasing. how can I do? can you show me some code snippets?

Comment: Note that you may need to use -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize to adjust how much memory the jvm will allow to be allocated to direct byte buffers. The default behavior varies between versions, vendors, architectures, and other options.

Comment: Why do you think you need a buffer that big?