# Java: what is the official way to store large data (>2GB) in memory?

Tags: java, memory, large-data

It is well known limitation that the common way to store data in `byte[]` arrays is limited to 2^31 bytes (2GB).

There are plenty of Java bug reports and Java specification requests that address this issue. Some of them has been files at the beginning of this century!

However all related entries I found were closed and/or marked as duplicate. In the mean time every consumer PC has enough memory so that this issue gets more and more important.

Therefore I am asking myself:

**What is th (Java) official way to handle large in-memory data? E.g. storing 4GB in RAM**

If there is no official solution what is the common solution used by the community?

Note: I consider saving the data to a temporary files not as a solution. Servers with more than 100GB RAM are not uncommon...

Comment: What do you mean by "official"? What data are you going to store? What do you want to to with the stored data?

Comment: in-memory data very rarely consists of bytes. Most of the time, it consists in Java objects. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto what difference does it make? OP is asking how to store more than 2GBs of binary data in the main memory.

Comment: @f1sh As @JBNizet mentioned, data usually is not just a big chunk of bytes. Even if it is, it could be split into pieces, and could be put into a collection of `byte` arrays...

Comment: Just an idea (I didn't try myself), but what about using a `LongBuffer`? Theoretically you may reach 8GB

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as an "official" way. I have never met anything about this problem in the official Java language specification.

But generally saying, you can always represent such a big array as array of arrays, i.e. `byte[][]`. In this case each element of the top-level array will describe a "page" of your storage. This will allow you to store theoretically 2^31x2^31=2^62 bytes.

Comment: That would be a solution, but is it really necessary that every developer that faces this problem again needs to implement to logic again? Isn't there a common code or library available that abstract the underlaying implementation and provides a `byte[]` similar interface? E.g. reading data from a stream, saving data to a stream, accessing certain elements?

Comment: This is a very broad question. It depends on what kind of data you want to store and how do you want to deal with it

Answer (score 2):

Java, as general-purpose language, does not have neither specific instruments for handling large in-memory data out of the box, nor any special official recommendations for it so far.

You have the following options while using Java to work with as much memory as possible under single JVM:

- As already mentioned in this thread - rely on in-heap arrays of arrays, even better on arrays of [java.nio.Buffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html) wrappers for those arrays
- Maintain bunch of off-heap direct [java.nio.ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)'s taking care about capacity of each one due to constraints of the 32 bit indexing. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24026948/8513835). Also [memory-mapped files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html) have to be mentioned here
- Use in-process in-memory database like [H2](http://www.h2database.com) keeping in mind its own [limitations](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#limits_limitations) (H2 also even can rely on [own in-memory file system](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#file_system))
- Use off-process memory storage like [Memcached](https://memcached.org/) with corresponding [Java client](https://redislabs.com/lp/memcached-java/)
- Set up [RAM disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive) (or use [tmpfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs), or something like that) and work with memory as with a file system from Java
- ...

Each and any approach has own drawbacks and advantages in terms of read/write speed, footprint, durability, maintainability, etc. At the same time it depends on the nature of objects being stored in memory, their lifecycle, access scheme, etc.

So desired choice must be elaborated by strictly matching it against particular requirements/use cases.

Answer (score 1):

As the existing good answers by Andremoniy and Kostiantyn are not what I had in mind I investigated the topic a bit deeper.

What I originally had in mind was a library or code snippet of a Java class that handles all the magic internally (e.g. chunking the data to multiple byte arrays). But as questions asking for library recommendations are immediately closed because of some stupid rule I could not write that in my question.

This this the collection of what I found regarding existing solutions:

## [fastutil: BigArrays](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/)

- Package name: it.unimi.dsi.fastutil
- License: Apache commons
- [BigArrays JavaDoc](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/BigArrays.html)

Provides monodimensional arrays with 64-bit indices. It uses multiple `byte[]` to store the data internally. It seems to be developed to store large arrays of numbers as it provides methods for sorting the values in the array.

Negative: Accessing a `BigArrays` seems to be a bit complicated as there is no adaption to `InputStream` or `OutputStream`.

## [elasticsearch BigArray](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch)

The elsasticsearch project contains classes that allow handling of large byte (and other primitive) arrays.
The important classes are located in the package [org.elasticsearch.common.util](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/util).

The disadvantage is that the classes are only available as part of the elasticsearch core library, which is pretty large and has additionally a lot of dependencies.
However as it uses the Apache 2.0 license extracting and repackaging the necessary classes seems to be a reasonable way.

## Notes

I found a very interesting hint that Sun planned back in 2009 to provide a class named `BigByteBuffer` for Java NIO.2. In 2010 Oracle bought Sun and now 8 years later we still have neither `BigByteBuffer` nor `byte[]` with 64bit indices...