# Java ByteBuffer: How to allocate a buffer of capacity size type LONG?

Tags: java, bytebuffer

Currently getting integer overflow on `ByteBuffer allocate(int capacity)` in Java, where capacity > max value of integer in Java. How can I allocate a byte buffer of capacity larger than INTEGER.MAX_VALUE?

Comment: Do you have more than **2 TB** of RAM?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JAVA NIO Bytebuffer.allocateDirect() size limit over the int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026918/java-nio-bytebuffer-allocatedirect-size-limit-over-the-int)

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code this of `HeapByteBuffer.class` it uses byte array under the hood:

```
HeapByteBuffer(int cap, int lim, MemorySegmentProxy segment) {            
    super(-1, 0, lim, cap, new byte[cap], 0, segment);
    this.address = ARRAY_BASE_OFFSET;
}
```

As you probably know it is impossible to allocate array with length more then `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

I can suggest using other data structure like `List<Byte>` or `Set<Byte>`